# Linux: How to reset the bluetooth adapter without rebooting the operating system?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver

1. I have an onboard bluetooth device that stops working a few hours after booting with this error. I can not understand what is the reason for this behavior, so I decided to use an another method.
   I need to reboot the bluetooth adapter without restarting the operating system.
   [image]
2. Using `ls -lA /sys/class/bluetooth/` , I make sure that the PCI address of the buggy device in the system logs belongs to Bluetooth:
   [image]
3. Using `find /sys | grep drivers.*00:04.1`, I find out which driver `00:04.1` is bound to:
   [image]
4. I successfully unbind the `HSU serial` driver from `00:04.1` by using `echo -n "0000:00:04.1" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/"HSU serial"/unbind`. You can see that `hciconfig` doesn't output anything:
   [image]
5. But I can't bind the `HSU serial` driver back to `00:04.1`. `No such device` error occurs:
   [image]
6. I also tried to specify the vendor `8086` and device name `1191`, it did not help:
   [image]
7. Using `lspci -nn`, I saw that device `00:04.1` exists in the operating system:
   [image]

How do I get the Bluetooth adapter to work, either by binding a driver to it, or by fixing the original bug that caused Bluetooth to crash?

Comment: Do not put text as pictures. Copy/paste the text.

Comment: Dosn't `bluetoothctl power off`/`bluetoothctl power on` work rather than mucking about with sys files? If it does, then you can start debugging it from there.

Comment: bluetoothctl power off / on throws no errors, but when I try to use the hci0 device, I get a connection-timeout error. Restarting the bluetooth service does not help.

Comment: The problem sounds like it's coming from static electricity.

Comment: Does `lsmod` show any drivers relevant to this device? Doing an `rmmod <driverName>` and either `modprobe <driverName>` or `insmod <driverName>` might bring it back up...

Comment: @Mokubai, Yes, lsmod shows bcm_bt_lpm module. But when I enter rmmod bcm_bt_lpm, the system freezes up.

Comment: @Mokubai, I can run the command above if I block bluetooth with rfkill. But trying to load a module causes a crash in the kernel.

Comment: Yeah, could be that if the hardware gets into an odd state then the driver might not be able to properly reinitialise it without a full power cycle. Maybe you can reset the device using the commands at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73908/how-to-reset-cycle-power-to-a-pcie-device

Answer (score 1):

I had strange problems with bluetooth prior to updating to 20.04 (focal)

This script did the trick then, may  be it is a "fix" for your problem too:

```
$ type -a bt
bt is a function
bt () 
{ 
    case $1 in 
        on)
            rfkill unblock bluetooth
        ;;
        off)
            rfkill block bluetooth
        ;;
        *)
            echo "use: bt on | off";
            return 1
        ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Just a combination of commands rfkill block bluetooth ; rfkill unblock bluetooth provokes this problem! Great, now I can debug this problem without waiting hours after the system boots.

Comment: edit: Had corrected that in the "in use" version, not here though :-p

Answer (score 0):

For me i first updated the bluetooth firmware: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1542743

Then what magically resets the bluetooth adapter when it crashes, was this command which removes mod:

```
sudo rmmod ath3k
```

followed by this command which re-inserts mod:

```
sudo modprobe ath3k
```

I guess this works if you have atheros bluetooth driver. Other modules are btusb and btintel, try these too.

Answer (score 0):

`service bluetooth restart` possibly in combination with `sudo`